# How enable disabled custom validator using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, customvalidator

i have a disabled custom validator that i want do enable it using jquery.
how can i do that?
the code below works for RequiredFieldValidators but Not for CustomValidators :

```
        ValidatorEnable($('#cvPass'), true);
```

what is the solution?
**EDIT:**
i am using server-side validation, not client side.
when we are using client side validation there is no problem about enabling and disabling Custom Validator.
thanks for the nice simple codes of @Josh Mein

thanks in advance

Comment: I posted an additional comment within my answer which I think will inform you about what could be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not have any issue with what you have tried. Here is a quick example that worked for me:

**HTML**:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_Test" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="val_Test" ValidateEmptyText="true" ClientValidationFunction="MyValidation" ControlToValidate="txt_Test" ErrorMessage="Test"></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_Test" Text="Test" onclick="btn_Test_Click" />
<input type="button" value="disable validator" onclick="disableValidator()" />
<input type="button" value="enable validator" onclick="enableValidator()" />
```

**Javscript**:

```
function enableValidator() {
    ValidatorEnable($('[id$=val_Test]')[0], true);
}

function disableValidator() {
    ValidatorEnable($('[id$=val_Test]')[0], false);
}

function MyValidation(sender, args) {
    if ($('[id$=txt_Test]').val() == "")
        args.IsValid = false;
}
```

**Edit**: With your new information, I believe I know what is the problem. Before server validation starts, the page is reloaded which causes the validator to be set to disabled because according to the server that was its last known state. This is because validators are not controls whose values are posted back to the server. You could set a hiddenField with a value that could tell the server to validate the control.

Comment: thanks for the answer / but you disabled it and i think there is no problem about that. i want to enable a disabled CustomValidator!!

Comment: so sorry man, i forgot to tell you that i am using server-side validation. your simple codes worked for both ways. but what about server side validatin?

Comment: What type of field are you validating?

Comment: i am checking user name and password with that custom validator. however thanks for the edit. using hidden field is a good idea, so i accepted your answer.

Comment: Why would it ever be disabled?

Comment: by on blur of another text box (email - uses PagesMethods) i will enable that disabled custom validator (with it's related text box). the display of that custom validator is none at first page load(also it's text box) and i will show it on blur of that email text box.

Comment: so in some situations i want to use that custom validator and in the other ones do n't...